# RowFilter in HBase

Tags: java, hbase

I have 20 rows in an HBase table and the rowkey is in long format starting from 1 to 20. I want to query the records from this where the rowkey starts with 1. I tried with `PrefixFilter` and `BinaryPrefixComparator` but it is working fine only if the rowkey is in string fromat. if it is in long the query returns all the records. How can I achieve this?

Filter expression

```
Scan scan=new Scan();
Filter rowFilter=new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryPrefixComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1")));
//Filter rowFilter=new RowFilter(CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL, new BinaryPrefixComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1")));
scan.setFilter(rowFilter);
ResultScanner resultscanner=htable.getScanner(scan);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the row keys are `long`, you have to refer them as `long` in your query rather than String. 
I.e: instead of `Bytes.toBytes("1")` use *`Bytes.toBytes(1L)`*.

You can set the range to be scanned:

```
scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(1L));
scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(21L));  //since stopRow is exclusive
```